# How to do payment using stripe

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I am using **Stripe** to make payment in my application. I got the token Successfully. 
I want to know that how the charges will be done, as there is no changes reflected in my Stripe dashboard. I'm using my Stripe Account **TestPublish Key**.

Answer (score 2):

Tokens only represent a card or payment method, not an actual transaction.

Once you've collected and tokenized a customer's payment information, you need to send the token to your backend server so you can use it in an API request, e.g. a [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) or [customer creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).

You can find more information in this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/charges

Answer (score -2):

Common error - you need to test on a real device, not the simulator. Just one of the gotchas of the Stripe API.